# How can I use Commerce API in order to add data to the Shared Environments database?

Tags: sitecore-commerce, sitecore-api, sql-database, odata, context

I made a `Sitecore API` and registered a Router, and after that, I called it through `PostmanAPI`. I write a command process to add data to the database but follow the default when inheriting from `CommerceODataController`. The default environment is global, with `CommerceContext` being the `CurrentContext`. As expected, the data will be in the Shared Environments database, but it is in the Global database
(I use `Sitecore 10.1`. Maybe not much different compared with `Sitecore 9`)

[image]

```
[HttpPut]
    [ODataRoute("PostNoteSettingCommand()", RouteName = "api")]
    public async Task<IActionResult> SampleCommand([FromBody] ODataActionParameters value)
    {
        if (!ModelState.IsValid || value == null)
        {
            return new BadRequestObjectResult(ModelState);
        }

        if (!value.ContainsKey("MyName") || string.IsNullOrEmpty(value["MyName"]?.ToString()))
        {
            return new BadRequestObjectResult(value);
        }

        var name = value["MyName"].ToString();
        var displayName = value["DisplayName"].ToString();
        var message = value["Message"].ToString();
        var entity = value["Entity"].ToString();
        var discount = "0";
        var feedback = "";

        var objectProcess = new CreateSettingArg(name, displayName, message, discount, entity, feedback);

        var command = Command<CreateSettingCommand>();


        CurrentContext.AddPolicyKeys("AddSetting");


        var result = await command.Process(CurrentContext, objectProcess).ConfigureAwait(false);

        return new ObjectResult(result);
    }
```

CreateSettingCommand

```
 public async Task<Setting> Process(CommerceContext commerceContext, CreateSettingArg arg)
    {
        using (var activity = CommandActivity.Start(commerceContext, this))
        {
            var setting = new Setting
            {
                Id = arg.Name.ToEntityId<Setting>(),
                DisplayName = arg.DisplayName,
                Name = arg.Name,
                IsApprove = false,
                Message = arg.Message,
                Discount = arg.Discount,
                Feedback = arg.Feedback
            };

            var listMemberShipComponent = setting.GetComponent<ListMembershipsComponent>();
            if (!listMemberShipComponent.Memberships.Contains(CommerceEntity.ListName<Setting>()))
            {
                listMemberShipComponent.Memberships.Add(CommerceEntity.ListName<Setting>());
                setting.SetComponent(listMemberShipComponent);
            }

            var transientListMembershipComponent = setting.GetComponent<TransientListMembershipsComponent>();
            if (!transientListMembershipComponent.Memberships.Contains(CommerceEntity.ListName<Setting>()))
            {
                transientListMembershipComponent.Memberships.Add(CommerceEntity.ListName<Setting>());
                setting.SetComponent(transientListMembershipComponent);
            }

            var persistResult = await _commerceCommander.PersistEntity(commerceContext, setting);

            return persistResult
                ? setting
                : null;
        }
    }
```

When I create a custom plugin in Business Tools, the command processor will use `context.CommerceContext` and data will be added to the Shared Environments database

[image]

Same command, but in a different context. How can I add the data to the Shared Environments database when I use the Sitecore API?

[image]

```
[PipelineDisplayName("DoActionAddSetting")]
public class DoActionAddSetting : AsyncPipelineBlock<EntityView, EntityView, CommercePipelineExecutionContext>
{
    private readonly CommerceCommander _commerceCommander;

    public DoActionAddSetting(
        CommerceCommander commerceCommander)
    {
        this._commerceCommander = commerceCommander;
    }

    public override async Task<EntityView> RunAsync(EntityView entityView, CommercePipelineExecutionContext context)
    {
        if (entityView == null
            || !entityView.Action.Equals(context.GetPolicy<SettingsUiPolicy>().AddSettingActionName, StringComparison.OrdinalIgnoreCase))
        {
            return entityView;
        }
```

Comment: Please update your question so your code examples are in code blocks instead of screenshots.

Comment: I never face this issue but Shared DB is configured in Plugin.SQL.PolicySet-1.0.0.json file. Check the configuration if it is pointing to correct DB.

Comment: I had added code to the question.